# Why no ConfigAndLog or Templates_C folders on my test system

Tags: drupal, configandlog

I've recreated my 5.35.2 test system (several times!) on Drupal 7, using the default directories.  All is working OK but there isn't a ConfigAndLog or a Templates_C folder. The 'View Log' extension is working, but I can't see these folders anywhere.

Comment: Sounds to me like they exist but your're looking in the wrong place!  If you go to Administer > System Settings > Directories and click the help icon in the top message box, you should get a pop-up with the path variables, including [civicrm.files].  Are your missing files under there?

Comment: [civicrm.files] is exactly where I'm looking.  You are correct, I was looking in the wrong place - they are in /home/acivior1/public_html/./private/civicrm I guess because in Drupal the 'Private file system path' was defined as './private'   I figured this from looking at the civicrm.settings files.

Comment: Ah, good you've found them!

Comment: I think this occurred because I've reloaded the test system several time, without recreating Drupal 7.  Civi must be looking in this Drupal field when it installs.  I'll know better next time!  This must rank as one of the dumbest questions on here...

Comment: Probably worth creating an answer explaining what you looked at to figure out where they are,

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out by looking at my civicrm settings file - in which `CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR` was defined to be in `/home/acivior1/public_html/./private/civicrm/templates_c`.  This was because the Drupal private file system path was defined as `./private` so this is where Civi put these files when installing.  However I notice just above this definition the comments set out below. It appears that the install ignored it?

> ** The default excludes node_modules (can be huge), various CiviCRM
> dirs that are unlikely to have anything we need to scan inside, and
> (what could be your) Drupal's private file storage area.